# Typescript: How to apply the same function to different types of arrays

Tags: typescript

This typescript function shoud be applicable to two different types of arrays (i.e. arrays with different interfaces) which both have two properties (id and count) in common.
The function updates the count property of an item OR task with a given id.
But I get a typescript error at the "find" command: "The expression is not callable."
If I remove one of the Interfaces, i.e. if I only define the input parameter "items" as a Item-array (Item[]) OR an Task-array (Task[]) it works.
But I want to apply the function to both types of arrays.

```
//interface definitions
export interface Item {
    id: number,
    count: number,
    other: number
}
export interface Task {
    id: number,
    count: number,
    more: string
}

//function
function UpdateCount(items: Item[] | Task[], id: number, count: number) {
   let item = items.find(obj => obj.id === id);
   if (item !== undefined) {
      item.count = count;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

```
//interface definitions
interface BaseItem {
    id: number,
    count: number
}

export interface Item extends BaseItem {
    other: number
}
export interface Task extends BaseItem {
    more: string
}

//function
function UpdateCount<T extends BaseItem>(items: T[], id: number, count: number) {
   const item = items.find(i => i.id === id);
   if (!item) return; 
   item.count = count;
}
```

Comment: This also works, however this could get a little confusing if there's not really a relation between `Item` and `Task`.

Comment: You're definitely right, i forgot to add the generic type. Anyway he told that both of those items have at least id and count properties so i guessed that id and count could have been placed in the base interface

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a matter of fact: a Task ist just a variant of an Item (or the other way round). Since both are records from the same table, you could even say they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

The details in the error message are useful:

> Each member of the union type...has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

What it's saying is that this function signature:

```
find((obj: Item, index: number, array: Item[]): Item | undefined
```

and this function signature:

```
find((obj: Task, index: number, array: Task[]): Task | undefined
```

are incompatible.

In a comment, [captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian) pointed out a couple of relevant issues on the TypeScript issue list:

- [*Array.reduce doesn't work*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44063)
- [*.map() .reduce() .filter() methods fail with "This expression is not callable." error on valid array with union type*](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390)

You can solve it in a couple of ways. Probably the simplest is to define an interface that `Item` and `Task` can both extend:

```typescript
//interface definitions
interface Base {
    id: number,
    count: number,
}
export interface Item extends Base {
    other: number
}
export interface Task extends Base {
    more: string
}
```

Then the function can either just accept `Base`, or use a generic parameter that extends `Base`:

```typescript
function UpdateCount<ElementType extends Base>(items: ElementType[], id: number, count: number) {
   let item = items.find(obj => obj.id === id);
   if (item !== undefined) {
      item.count = count;
   }
}
```

You don't **have** to define the interface separately, you could just use `{id: number, count: number}` instead of `Base` in that function, but then if you change that common aspect of `Item` or `Task`, your function won't match them anymore.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAJteFSVAPbgDOAsAFAQwIroBCix6A3hWu2qBgFxrgCuAWwBGcADRsOyAvyi8BI8RQC+FYACpoADwAOBWJHXBOUOElRoAkjEFptMcBmJoGTNK3Ic0BSAAs48kKisCpqmrr6hsZUZrRoACqMANZ2Wg5OLowskuyC+tC8xJCwEADmoeRqwPCyyPhEFDXgdYTgaACqOhiIMADCMlAAPACiADbQgtBQ8QCeOuj2Uxmu0AB8ABR4E8S8YxNTkLPzANoAumKcPHxB4mjSspCBirAAlO4545CcNmgAvN-bAB0OEc6wIwgAVn9Vt5IYCuH9fv8uC8ANw5UDwNCbH4AQiRaFkWBB0Awbw8XnYW0EgPuUD+dwGkHRnnYqnIyiAA)

Comment: I think these issues worth mentioning: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44063 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Oh, interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.

```js
//interface definitions
export interface Item {
    id: number,
    count: number,
    other: number
}
export interface Task {
    id: number,
    count: number,
    more: string
}

//function
function UpdateCount<K extends { id: number, count: number }>(
  items: K[],
  id: number,
  count: number
) {
   let item = items.find(obj => obj.id === id);
   if (item !== undefined) {
      item.count = count;
   }
}
```

What that is basically saying is that Items will be an array of some type which includes an `id` and a `count` property. So long as what you pass into that function has those two properties, it should be good.